# How do I suppress showing cents on a contribution page?

Tags: civicontribute

I'm offering several prices on a contribution page:
() $10.00 Bronze
() $100.00 Silver
() $1000.00 Gold

I'd want to remove the decimal, because no suggested amount has cents, but can't figure out is there is a setting or if I need to dig into the code (and possibly write an extension?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Settings - Localization, try changing Monetary Value Display from:

```
%!i
```

to:

```
%!.0i
```

See: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,20941.msg87684.html#msg87684

Please see the comments below by Andrew Hunt and Lobo - the above will get rid of cents/pence across the board, which may not be what you want. See Lobo's answer for alternative approaches. Trust Lobo. :-)

Comment: The problem with this is that you will be getting rid of cents everywhere, not just on the contribution page.  If you have any contributions, event fees, or payment processor fees that are a fraction of a dollar, they'll appear just as the whole dollar (though they should be recorded in the database correctly).

Comment: The above is a global change and is probably not desired. I suspect the user wants this for public facing pages only

Answer (score 3):

If this is localized to one specific page, then i'd probably do this via a jQuery snippet on that page.

If this is desired for all public facing pages, I suspect a buildForm hook will allow you to modify the labels of the various price set elements

Answer (score 2):

One option If using a priceset you can choose to not display the price and show price in the description in the formatyou want. However the price will show with decimals on subsequent pages (confirmations, etc.)